# What's wrong with my Reverse LinkedList program, gives stack overflow error.

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

The logic looks right to me, i'm not really sure where its breaking.
Please help.

```
static Node sol(Node head,Node prev, Node next) {

    if(next.next == null) 
    {
        head = next;
        return head;
    }
    if(prev!=next) {
        next.next = prev;
        prev = next;
    }


    return sol(head, prev, next.next);

}
```

function call:

```
sol(head,head,head);
```

Comment: I don't know.. what is wrong with it? Do you get an error? Not correct output?

Comment: Why do you think it is not right?

Comment: Yes, stack overflow 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at linkedlists.Reverse.sol(Reverse.java:41)

Comment: It is supposed to reverse the linked list.

Comment: Is this a circular linked list?

Comment: No, its a regular singly linked list.

Comment: You're making a circular linked list by assigning head.next to head

Comment: @gregory, I thought it was traversing to the next node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code stands, you'll skip the `if (prev != next) {}` block on the first iteration as you intend, but on the second iteration, the `next.next` field is prematurely pointed to the `prev` node. When you recurse using `next.next` as a parameter, you're in a circular loop between `prev` and `next` nodes until the stack blows.

Beyond this, the function header you've chosen uses an extra parameter, which isn't strictly necessary, complicates your function logic and passes burden onto the caller. I'd recommend something like the following:

```
static Node sol(Node head, Node prev) {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (head.next == null) {
        head.next = prev;
        return head;
    }

    Node tail = sol(head.next, head);
    head.next = prev;
    return tail;
}
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/BustlingRealGeeklog)

Call this with `sol(head, null);`. The base case is when the head is null or the last node in the chain. Once the tail has been located, it's passed backward through recursion to the caller as the new head. `head.next = prev` reverses a link in the list along the way back.

The key difference between this and your code is where the recursive call happens; if you perform reversals on the way back up the call stack after retrieving the head, you're in better shape to avoid misplacing your `next` references.

Comment: Thank you Soo much ggorlen, this was the best explanation.
I've just been soo used to doing iterative, that i suck at recursion.
Tried to work my head around recursion+LinkedList... couldnt do.

Thank you very much again.

Can you please suggest me the best way to master recursion. I have only been able to do simple problems like fibo, factorial and counting steps. 

Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Just keep practicing a bunch of example problems and walk through your logic one step at a time.